# Where did these creepy google/gmail icons come from?

Tags: applications, google-chrome, launchpad

I just noticed them, I suspect/hope Chrome somehow placed them there, they are not removable by normal methods, they only open Chrome when clicked and nothing else

Google is getting pretty creepy, when a new thing appears that I didn't put, I generally suspect malware

(Photos icon kept for context)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

After slightly more digging, I see that Chrome **now** (it's a new behaviour, likely 2-3 months old) bundles them with new installs, since I use the chrome command separately to create new instances, it added those icons just now, for that instance specifically, so when I click them, they just open the main Chrome and not the webpages

Still pretty creepy tho, they seem to be only removable from ~/Applications - and a restart is probably needed for a refresh

Edit: After a while the icons disappear after removing the files